# How to rank monthly data, using both trends and averages

Tags: machine-learning, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics, order-statistics

I have a very large data set containing the daily searches for some Wikipedia entries. 
I am using the number of searches as proxy of popularity and want to rank the entries. 
Lets say I have entities `{e1,e2,...,en}` and the daily number of searches per entity as following

```
e_1:   {d1_1 d1_2 ... d1_30}
e_2:   {d2_1 d2_2 ... d2_30}
.
.
.
e_n:   {dn_1 dn_2 ... dn_30}
```

Where `{dn_1 dn_2 ... dn_30}` are the daily searches for entry `e_n`.
I want to rank the Wikipedia entries, using number of searches( proxy pf popularity) per month ( `di_1 di_2 ... di_30` )
The simplest way, was to calculate the median/mean 30-day searches and sort entries accordingly, however the results were not satisfactory.
 For one thing the data is very noisy. I am looking for a ranking algorithm that would somehow combine the central measures (mean/median) with the 30-day trend (slope of a 30-day regression??) and return a score that will enable me to sort the entries, accordingly.

As an example, if `e_1 and e_2` have same means, but there was a sharper increase in number of searches for `e_2`, then `e_2` would be considered more popular than `e_1`.
-- The data is large so the algorithm should not be very computational intensive.
-- Can't use a Matrix implementation of the above data. The algorithm should calculate a popularity score for each entry independent of the rest of the data.
Any suggestion?

Comment: What are $\{\mbox{dn]_1,\ldots,\mbox{dn]_{30}\}$?

Comment: These are daily searches for each entry

Answer (score 1):

One approach for this would be to use [Poisson regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression). You could do a separate Poisson regression for each entry: after estimating the regression parameters, you could substitute the current day (e.g., $x=30$) into the model of the mean, to estimate the current popularity. Alternatively, you could model each entry as a time series of counts.

These techniques would enable you to more effectively estimate the "current" popularity, as opposed to the average popularity over the entire month. However, if the data are "noisy", you should still expect to get large margins of error -- these techniques do not really address the problem of having noisy data. For that, some things you could do would be to (1) collect more data (e.g., going back further than 30 days), or (2) aggregate the data in some way prior to performing the analysis, e.g. by lumping together related Wikipedia entries instead of considering each entry separately.

Comment: Let me look into this in more details. Thanks for the comment